# Understanding filebeat monitoring stats when ingesting netflow traffic

Tags: monitoring, filebeat, netflow

I'm running filebeat 7.14.0 to ingest Netflow data, which is then stored in Elasticsearch and viewed on Kibana. When I run `filebeat -e`, I will see some logs generated by filebeat every 30s.

I'm trying to understand the stats more. For example, I see

`"input":{"netflow":{"flows":1234,"packets":{"dropped":2345,"received":12345}}}}`

But each netflow packet contains about 10 netflow records, so when I receive 12345 packets, I would expect 123450 flows, and the stats only show 1234 flows. Does it mean I'm missing a lot of flows?

Answer (score 0):

For Better understanding of logs , enable logging in **debug** mode and add
Logging.Selector : ["input"]
This will show you stats per sec in the logs .
Add grep "stats" while checking the log to easily check the stats .

This will show you Flows and packets per second